# Auto-increment ID in Google spreadsheet using Script

Tags: google-apps-script, auto-increment

I have the code below. It's supposed to increment ID upon entering "Yes" in col B.
It does the work to a certain extent, but it always keep the number of zeros the same while it's supposed to decrease by 1 when ID reach 10s and by 2 when it reaches 100s etc.

```
function onEdit(e){

  var AUTOINC_COLUMN = 0;
  var HEADER_ROW_COUNT = 1;
  
var zeros = "000000";

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var worksheet   = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet6");
  var rows        = worksheet.getDataRange().getNumRows()-1;
  var vals        = worksheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, rows+1, 2);
  
  var r = worksheet.getActiveCell();
  if (r.getColumn() == 2 && worksheet.getName()=='Sheet6' && r.getValue() == "Yes") { 
  
  for (var rowx = HEADER_ROW_COUNT; rowx < vals.length; rowx++) {
    try {
      var id = vals[rowx][AUTOINC_COLUMN];
      Logger.log(id);Logger.log((""+id).length ===0);
      if ((""+id).length === 0) {
        
        worksheet.getRange(rowx+1, AUTOINC_COLUMN+1).setValue("STU" + ("0".repeat(zeros.length - rowx.toString.length)) + rowx);
        
      }
    } catch(ex) {
          }
  }
  }
}
```

It seems the toString function is not returning the right value for some reason. Can someone please help?

[image: Screenshot of the results I see and the results I'd like to see]

Comment: can you show a screenshot of a sample file?

Comment: @NaziA just did. In columns A and B the results I get, and in columns B and C the results I would like to see. I highlighted rows 9 and 10 where the difference is.

Comment: Added the answer below, that should answer your issue. If it did help you, feel free to choose the answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While checking your code, I've seen that you are not using `toString` as method, causing it to return the number length which is always 1.

Just change it to `toString()` and it should work.
I've tested it on my side and it did do what you expect.

Sample output:

[image: sample table]

For additional reference, please see the [usage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp)

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help. Good use of other methods as well. Very clean code. Clean it up.